# Put Parrot OS terminal in one line like ubuntu or kali?

Tags: terminal, prompt, parrot-os

Using Parrot OS I could see that the terminal is like this:

```
┌─[root@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ #
```

It is possible to change it to one line like in kali? Like this one:

kali@kali:~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exec this command:

```
export PS1="\u@\h\$ "
```

to set your prompt to be like:

```
romeo@cbl-mariner$
```

this show username and hostname on the prompt. To make it permanently exec

```
echo 'PS1="\u@\h\$ "'>>~/.bashrc
```

so on next login you will have it

If you want to add path add `\w` to the string. And check [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/) for other ideas.

Comment: Thank you so much man!